# FFmpeg.AutoGen decoding an image using av_image_copy_to_buffer

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I try to use `FFmpeg.AutoGen.av_image_copy_to_buffer` to get decoded data into my application defined frame_buffer like so:

```
bytes_decoded = ffmpeg.av_image_copy_to_buffer(frame_data, buffer_size, frame->data, frame->linesize, 
                                               codCtx->pix_fmt, codCtx->width, codCtx->height, 1);
```

However the type of the parameter `frame->data` is of type `FFmpeg.AutoGen.byte_ptrArray8`, but the interface expects `FFmpeg.AutoGen.byte_ptrArray4`.
Does anyone know how to convert this parameter, so that I can pass it to the interface? VS complains with the following error message:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1503)

Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Comment: That doesn’t look like C#

Comment: Did you try this?

byte_ptrArray4 ptr4 = new byte_ptrArray4();
ptr4.UpdateFrom(frame->data.ToArray());